# dsPIC30F - How to configure max performance crystal?

Tags: pic, fft

I was looking at Table 20-1, *Oscillator Operating Modes*, in the [Microchip dsPIC30F datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/70138c.pdf), but I'm not sure which configuration will give me the best performance. I want to do an FFT and I need the best performance. I use PIC CSS C Compiler.

Which configuration do I need, and what crystal and capacitors should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically for programming the more advanced Microchip processors (PIC18/24/32, dsPIC30/33), you need more than the device datasheet to understand the details of operation (for example, how to get the most MIPS).

This information is found in the [dsPIC 30F Family Reference Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70046E.pdf) in Chapter 7. Specifically, a summary of the modes are found in Section 7.5, and a detailed document regarding choosing the values of the capacitors is found in Section 7.7. Notice that Fcy = Fosc/4, therefore to achieve the maximum device performance of 30 MIPS, you need to have Fosc = 30 * 4 = 120 MHz. One way to do this is to have a crystal in 'XT + 16XPLL' mode at 7.5 MHz, which should give you exactly 30 MIPS (7.5 * 16 / 4). You will quickly find that 7.5 MHz is not a common frequency, since it is not a multiple of the common serial port baud-rates. The closest is usually 7.3728 MHz, which will give you a slight reduction in performance, but let you use the standard baud rates (e.g. it is 115200 * 64).